# CD for Jenkins changes

Tags: jenkins

In our production jenkins we have many jobs.
The operators change the job configuration and script that run in CI.

Sometimes this change causes a failure. I searched the way how to do CD for this change.

I thought about creating a staging jenkins, but I see a problem with jobs sync ( I don't want to copy/merge the config.xml files).

What is the best way to use CD for these Jenkins changes?